# Change a sidebar menu to drop down menu when the screen is minimized

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Using Zurb Foundation 5 framework, I would like to convert a sidebar menu into dropdown on smaller devices and selecting an option (say for e.g.,selecting a checkbox) on the larger device reflects on the smaller one.

Suppose I have a sidebar menu that contains checkboxes like the one below:

```
<div class="row ">
<div class = "medium-4 large-3 columns show-for-medium-up"> 
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Apple</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Banana</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Orange</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Mango</li>
</ul>
</div> </div>
```

I want to convert this menu to dropdown on smaller devices. I tried the following:

```
<div class="show-for-small-only" id="sidebar-small" >
    <button data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false">Select Fruits <i class="fi-arrow-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown content" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Apple</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Banana</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Orange</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1">Mango</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But what i want is when I check, say for eg., Apple on a desktop, I want it to be checked on the smaller device as well and vice versa.

I know that for converting a top bar to drop-down menu, there is "toggle-topbar menu-icon". But for my sidebar menu, How do I convert it to the drop down menu reflecting the changes (check/uncheck the checkboxes) that are made on the larger screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't searched much about it, but I think you would have to update manually the values, so when you click on desktop you force an update for mobile and the other way too.

Comment: I am dealing with dynamic data. And I tried forcing the update like you had mentioned with Javascript too. I am not able to get the desired result.